# C# Extension formatting is not working for remote dev containers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

C# Extension and Omnisharp can format C# code inside VS Code.

But when I connect to a remote dev container, I lose this formatting feature.

And when inside a container I use `Ctrl+Shift+I` to format my C# code files, I see the ugly message saying that:

> There is no formatter for `cshapr` files installed

How can I fix this?

Comment: Open extensions and check if `Omnisharp` requires installation inside the container (VS should show the tip when you are connected to the container).

Comment: `Omnisharp` is already installed inside container. It's installed based on `.vscode` and `.devcontainer` configuration.

Comment: Open the command pallet and look for OmniSharp: Restart OmniSharp.  I had exactly the same issue today, and the restart worked for me.